# Strange CSS vertical text issue between desktop and mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have an `<h2>` element in which I'd like to vertically center the enclosed text. It looks right on desktop Chrome, but not on mobile (iOS) Chrome. I would hugely appreciate any insight into this issue. Below find links to screenshots on both (desktop first, mobile second):

[Desktop (correct behaviour).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAb64.jpg)
[Mobile (incorrect behaviour).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bZh6.jpg)

The HTML and CSS code is included below. I have abbreviated the HTML code for readability. Thanks so much, Internet!

HTML:

```
...
<body id="home">
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="i/splash.jpg" alt="" id="splash" />
        <div id="inner">
            <h2>hi!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
...
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS RESET */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, div, ul#nav, ul#nav li, ul#nav li a, img#splash {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
    background: url('i/bg.jpg') fixed repeat;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* WALBAUM WEBFONT */

@font-face {
    font-family: Walbaum;
    src: url('f/WalbaumMTStd-Regular.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Walbaum;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('f/WalbaumMTStd-Medium.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Walbaum;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url('f/WalbaumMTStd-MediumIt.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Walbaum;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url('f/WalbaumMTStd-Italic.otf');
}

/* MAIN */

#main {
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* HEADER */

#header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#logo {
    float: none;
    width: 358px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#logo a, #logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

#subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #3f3f3f;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

#subtitle strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #982020;
}

ul#nav {
    font-family: Walbaum, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

ul#nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 42px 2px 18px 2px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 7px;
}

ul#nav:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#nav li#music a {
    color: #d86619;
}

ul#nav li#photos a {
    color: #1787ac;
}

ul#nav li#code a {
    color: #17ac3a;
}

ul#nav li#about a {
    color: #a317ac;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* CONTENT */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

#content img#splash {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #191919;
    background-color: rgba(25,25,25,0.3);
    margin: 0 auto 0 -6px;
}

#content #inner {
    width: 100%;
}

#content #inner h2 {
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Walbaum, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #333333;
    background-color: rgba(75,75,75,0.1);
    margin: 0 auto 10px -6px;
    text-shadow: 0.08em 0.08em 0.05em #090909;
    padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

#content #inner p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

/* FOOTER */

#clear {
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

/* RESPONSIVENESS */

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #logo {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    #main {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }

    #content img#splash {
        max-width: 75%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #content #inner {
        width: 22.5%;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 521px) {
    #main {
        max-width: 95%;
    }

    #content #inner {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) and (min-width: 359px) {
    ul#nav {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }

    ul#nav li {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #main {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 95%;
    }

    #content #inner {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 358px) {
    #logo {
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul#nav {
        padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    ul#nav li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    }

    #main {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 95%;
    }

    #content #inner {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    ul#nav {
        padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    }

    ul#nav li {
        width: 45%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #subtitle {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem here is, that mobile browsers resize your `font-size`. It's not good practice, but you can avoid that by using:

```css
html {
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: @kalmenius, thanx! ;-) Too bad, maybe you could create a http://jsfiddle.net for your problem? Makes it easier to help.

Comment: @kalmenius, hmm... looks just fine in my android browser. So I can't help, sorry.

Comment: Yes, there it is. Have you tested another font?

Answer (score 0):

Use `em` for your font sizing - this will adjust it properly for different window sizes:

```css
#inner h2 {
  font-size: 1em
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked in multiple browsers(web/Mobile). All is working fine for me.
However, 3 possible problems you may have-

1) The font problem

2) Mobile-Web resize Problem if not in a fluid layout.

3) Cache set